# express 4+socket.io or express.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, express.io

i'm trying to implement a realTime notification system for my social platform , and i'm wondering if i should just upgrade to express.io or keep express4 and include socket.IO .
according to your experience are there any pitfalls i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A look at the `package.json` file of Express.io shows that it depends on Express 3.4.0. The current version of Express is 4.4.0.

So, ask yourself: Do you *really* want to stick to an old version of Express, including all bugs and security issues that might have been fixed meanwhile, and rely on a single developer (who is apparently neither related to Express nor to Socket.io) to keep all the things always up-to-date and compatible and so on?

If you ask me: This reminds me of Knockback, which brought together Knockout and Backbone, and never really took off, for similar reasons as outlined above.

Personally, I'd stick with the original ones and do the little effort to combine them by myself.